# How to interpret waveguide multi-mode S-parameters in CST

Tags: waveguide

I have a cylindrical waveguide which is excited with two modes in each ports
as shown bellow.

However I cant see the meaning of S-params shown bellow.
photo one shows total  isolation(-100dB)

While photo 2 shown total path threw.(-0.17dB)

What is the meaning of those S-params?
Why one is very low and the other is almost 0 dB?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is plotted exactly ? please use the standard convention : S11 S21 S22. 
Looks like your first plot is S11. Thus almost no energy is bouncing back to the source port 1. And your second plot is S21. 
Thus almost all the energy in delivered to the port 2. But without knowing exactly what you are plotting, it's just guessing.

Comment: Its not stantart S11 S21 ,its a multimode simulation.
We excite several modes in the waveguide. i dont know how to interpret this kind of s_params.